# proving closure of a subset

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let B be a set, and let * be a binary operation in B. Suppose * satisfies the associative law. Let

$$P=\{b \in B : b * w = w * b \quad\forall\, w \in B\}$$

Prove that P is closed under *.

Comment: And as seen there, simply writing down what one has to show almost completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a,b\in P$, and we would like to show that $ab\in P$.

Since $a,b\in P$, we have that $a*w=w*a$ and $b*w=w*b$. Now, observe that
\begin{align*}
a*w&=w*a\\
a*w*b&=w*a*b
\end{align*}
Now, use $b*w=w*b$ on the first term.